# Highstocks component react error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am getting a following error while using highstocks in my react Project.
Here by attaching the Error and Code. please do help to get rid out of this error.

**Error**
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys (some property). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in Charts

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Charts from './Components/Charts.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Charts/>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

**Charts.js**

```
import HighCharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Charts extends Component {
render() {
  var data =  [
    [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
    [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 34.76],
    [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.34],
    [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 33.9]
  ];
  return (
    HighCharts.stockChart('root', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0
    },
    title: {
        text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
    },
    tooltip: {
        style: {
            width: '100%'
        },
        valueDecimals: 4,
        shared: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Exchange rate'
        }
      },
       series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data:data,
            id: 'dataseries'        
         }]
      })
   )}
}

export default Charts;
```

Comment: but what does  HighCharts.stockChart actually return?

Comment: if 'root' is a selector somewhere in your DOM model, then the render code should actually go to componentDidMount.. it would be much better to replace hardcoded `'root'` with a ref of a div produced by your `render()` method. If you still want to have this code inside `render` then just make it return null

Comment: thanks Daniel, root div is in my index.html where i can render all my components, Could you please give the rewritten code so, that i can understand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: highCharts.stockChart return a stock market chart with the data given in the code,

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't look like that, most likely it simply draws it and returns some sort of reference to it. Also react doesn't render stock charts, it only renders JSX statements and what they are transformed to...

Comment: i think its rendering the SVG content and within a second producing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately like that.. ideally the data should arrive with props

```
class Charts extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 34.76],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.34],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 33.9]
      ]
    };
  }

  setRef = ref => {
    if (!this.ref) {
      this.ref = ref;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {


    HighCharts.stockChart(this.ref, {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0
      },
      title: {
        text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
      },
      tooltip: {
        style: {
          width: '100%'
        },
        valueDecimals: 4,
        shared: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Exchange rate'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: data,
        id: 'dataseries'
      }]
    })


  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div ref={this.setRef} />
    );


  }
}

export default Charts;
```

Comment: I don't have a working example, most likely the ref doesn't come in properly. You should just check if `this.ref` exists in componentDidMount. It should but who knows

Comment: this is my  index.js                                                                              
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have fixed it. I have assigned Highstock.ctockchart to a variable and returned it in render method.